# XSL 1.0 Fastest way to find/replace node

Tags: xslt-1.0

what is the fastest method to find an specific node (has id or class)

This is slow:

```
/html/body[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' fooclass ')]//div[@id = 'fooClass'] 
//div[@id = 'fooClass']
//div[@class = 'fooClass']
```

I have an xsl with ~3000 lines an it needs about 20-40 seconds to render..

But how can I be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `//div[@id = 'fooClass']` should be the fastest...

You might think about a key. Something like

```
<xsl:key name="MyKey" match="//div" use="@id"/>
```

You'll find an example covering exactly your "id"-question here: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_key.asp

If your "id"-attributs are not always bound to "div"-tags, you can set the `match` to `match="//*"`, but - looking on performance - you'll get the best result, the closer you can define the path...